# Adding line in a file after head tag found using shell script

Tags: html, shell

I have many html files in the file system. I want to search all html files and add line  after  tag in all html files.
I want to do it using shell script.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) :

```
sed -i 's/<head>/<head>YOUR LINE HERE/g' ./*.html
```